# Max User Connections exception for mysql

Tags: java, mysql, tomcat

I am using mysql server as database and tomcat 7.0.57 on Mochahost server. Maximum 25 connections are given to me. Now, I am getting max_user connection exception. I searched everywhere but didnt get the solution. I tried Connection Pooling but webste is running very very slowly though im not getting any exception.

Comment: Are you making sure you're closing your connections once you are done with them?

Comment: Thanx for reply Matthew. Yes i have closed connections everywhere.